# Appending index to a list of lists, in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find a way to convert a `[[Int]]` to `[(Int, Int)]` pairs in haskell.

Eg, `[[1,2],[3,4]]` should become `[(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1)]`

I've been messing with zip and list comprehension to try to accomplish this, but I've yet to find even the slightest success. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you describe the rule for how you come up with `[(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1)]` from `[[1,2],[3,4]]` in words?

Comment: Its just appending the array index of the outer array onto the inner array, as a tuple. So, with the array a[] containing two arrrays, each one gets its index appended to it.

Comment: Keep the problem and your attempts to tackle it in the above space. It will be harder for posterity to follow if you leave it in the comment area.

Comment: I was answering a question someone asked.

Comment: Why don't you use an array library that has this functionality built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zipWith` function is a good starting point. Accordingly you may do like

```
Prelude> zipWith (\as i -> as >>= pure . flip (,) i) [[1,2],[3,4]] [0..] >>= id
[(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1)]
```

The final `>>= id` stage just concatenates the inner lists.

Comment: or `join . zipWith (map . flip (,)) [0..]`. (you can edit it in.) :)

Comment: @Will Ness No need..! It deserves a *glorious first comment* badge had there been one.

Comment: it's *your* code, I just massaged it a little bit. :)

Answer (score 3):

This function appends the coordinate value to the end of the tuple for every element in the list

```
let zipperfun coord pairlist =  map (\item->(item, coord)) pairlist
```

We use the previous function to create faux, a function that outputs a list of lists of tuples, (one per original list), Where each index is zipped to its corresponding tuples by applying zipperfun.

```
let faux lst = zipWith zipperfun [0..] lst
```

would produce

[[(1,0),(2,0)],[(3,1),(4,1)]]
Then we just concatenate the all the lists. This gives us a list of the desired tuples. We put this together in flattenerfun.

To create the following flattenerfun:

```
let flattenerfun lst = concat (faux lst)
```

Comment: There is a lot of very odd syntax there. Can you explain what is actually taking place and how you came to this answer?

Comment: Basically the auxiliary function just "zips" the indexes onto each of the tuples

Comment: You can see what happens by trying out the function that zipWith uses against a two element list.

Comment: I suppose I'll look at that. And why does this fail on on single element lists? eg [[1]] fails with ``*Main> addYIndex [[1]]
[(1,0),(*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large`` instead of producing (1,0)

Comment: it's currently implemented for 2-element lists. I'll edit this  by doing the inner op with a map